# Sorting numbers in string format with Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list that has some chapter numbers in string.
When I sort the keys using keys function, it gives me wrong results.

```
keys = ['1.1', '1.2', '2.1', '10.1'] 
keys.sort() 
print keys

['1.1', '1.2', '10.1', '2.1']
```

How can I use the sort function to get

```
['1.1', '1.2', '2.1', '10.1']
```

What if the array has something like this?

```
['1.1.1', '1.2.1', '10.1', '2.1'] -> ['1.1.1','1.2.1','2.1','10.1']
```

Comment: Prosseek try this: `keys.sort(key=float)` , I just learn [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474211/how-to-sort-python-list-of-strings-of-numbers/17474264#17474264)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
keys.sort(key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split('.')])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
keys.sort(key=StrictVersion)
```

Since chapter numbers are a subset of version numbers, this covers your needs.

Comment: Worked create for me. However, I used `LooseVersion` from the same module instead because I sort versions from an external source.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
keys.sort(key=lambda x: map(int, x.split('.')))
```

Comment: +1 This is a good answer for python2. In Python3 sorting maps no longer works, so you need to use `list(map(...))` which is uglier than the list comprehension in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a custom `key` argument to `sort` or `sorted`.

From http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

Comment: `>>> float('1.1.1')` ... `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.1.1`