# How to sort a Python list of strings of numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to sort list of strings containing numbers:

```
a = ["1099.0","9049.0"]
a.sort()
a
['1099.0', '9049.0']

b = ["949.0","1099.0"]
b.sort()

b
['1099.0', '949.0']

a
['1099.0', '9049.0']
```

But list `b` is sorting and not list `a`.

Comment: `a` is already sorted. `1` is smaller that `9`.

Comment: I want larger number to be at index `0` always and smaller number at index `0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting numbers in string format with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597099/sorting-numbers-in-string-format-with-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a list of version strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574080/sorting-a-list-of-version-strings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/how-to-sort-a-list-numerically)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You want to sort based on the `float` values (not string values), so try:

```
>>> b = ["949.0","1099.0"]
>>> b.sort(key=float)
>>> b
['949.0', '1099.0']
```

Answer (score 21):

Use a [lambda](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) inside 'sort' to convert them to float and then sort properly:

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: float(x))
```

So you will maintain them as strings, but sorted by value and not lexicographically.

Comment: @Keyser My point is you don't need a lambda, you can just use `key=float`.

Comment: to make my answer cool? actually, I forgot about the key functions. @Keyser using `sort(key=float)` achieves the same

Answer (score 13):

In case anybody is dealing with numbers and extensions such as 0.png, 1.png, 10.png, 2.png...
We need to retrieve and sort the characters before the extension since this extension does not let us to convert the names to floats:

```
myList = sorted(myList, key=lambda x: int(x[:-4]))
```

PD: After many years I have edited this answer changing float to int because I guess it is more efficient and more precise. It is a rare case to need floats for this purpose and it might bring errors.

Comment: remember to update the list too like
`myList = sorted(myList, key=lambda x: float(x[:-4]))`

Comment: If you want to update the list, you can also use `myList.sort(key=...)` instead of `sorted(myList, key=...)`,

Answer (score 3):

Convert them to `int` or `float` or even `decimal` (since it has trailing numbers)

```
>>> b = [float(x) for x in b]
>>> b.sort()
>>> b
[949.0, 1099.0]
```

Comment: This would mean changing the types of the elements in `b`, which may or may not be ideal.