# Can't sort my list using python built-in sorted() function

Tags: python

Why Sorted() function shows '1000' less than '996', '999' etc.

Sample Code:

```
 pyList = ['1000', '999', '996', '997', '998']

 print(sorted(pyList))
```

I expect the output: `['996', '997', '998', '999', '1000']`,

but the actual output is `['1000', '996', '997', '998', '999']`

Comment: It looks like the sort function is sorting your list alphabetically since the members are strings and not integers.

Comment: visit this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474211/how-to-sort-python-list-of-strings-of-numbers

Comment: Solved. Thx everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
sorted(pyList, key=int)
```

your elements are strings, and a string comparison is done from the first character to the last one

Comment: Since `int` is already a `callable`, you can do `key=int` :)

Comment: nice way to make the code shorter