# Sorting a list of strings of numbers does not provide the expected result

Tags: python

When I try to sort a list of strings of numbers with the following code it gives me a wrong result.

```py
n = list(input().split())

n.sort()

print(n)
```

for 
input = `10 11 100 200 300 34` , after sorting it gives
 `['10', '100', '11', '200', '300', '34']` where output should be `'10', '11', '34', '100', '200', '300']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort python list of strings of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474211/how-to-sort-python-list-of-strings-of-numbers)

Comment: hi @yatu i tried but it shows vote casted by less than 15 reputation are not counted.     BTW thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the list contains strings, and strings are sorted lexicographically. You need to cast the list items to `int`, *then sort*:

```
n = list(map(int, input().split()))
n.sort()
print(n)
# [10, 11, 34, 100, 200, 300]
```

Or if you want the resulting list to contain strings:

```
print(list(map(str, n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrong output you are receiving is due to lexical sorting instead of numerical sorting being applied, because you are operating on string.

What you want is:

```
n = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

n.sort()

print(n)
```